# Azure accounts for software/IT departments

Tags: azure

As software department we would like to move our software (currently working with Azure Pack) to the Azure cloud.
I've read about organizational accounts, but I couldn't find a clear descriptions of what they are. My doubts:

- are they required/suggested for a company that (at the moment) is not directly interested in Active Directory?
- which are the benefits?
- what's they price? Are they free to create and then the company only pays for resources used on azure, as it happens for ordinary accounts?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because we're not Microsoft.  Ask Microsoft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're asking about the mapping of organizational active directory OU with Azure. Actually you can login to your Azure cloud management portal in two ways:

1. Either with Microsoft account (@live.com;@outlook.com etc)
2. Or with your organizational account (@yourdomain.com)

And regarding your doubts:

1. It is not mandatory that you should make use of this feature. It is your organization wish that you make use of it or not.
2. The main benefit of making use of this feature is that, none of your clients require microsoft account to login to Azure portal. They can simply use their orgnaizational username for login and see the subscriptions they've been allowed to.
3. You may refer [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/active-directory/) for more details.